# Laravel belongsTo relation get "property of non-object"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a problem when I trying to get data from a belongsTo relation.

User

```
    public function profileImage()
    {
        $this->morphClass = 'profileImage';
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
    }
```

and in Post

```
    protected $with = ['creator'];

    protected $hidden = ['creator'];

    protected $appends = ['creator_image'];

    public function getCreatorImageAttribute()
    {
        return $this->creator->profileImage->url;    // Error
//        return dd($this->creator->profileImage->url);   // dd line
    }


    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','creator_id');
    }
```

and in database table:

```
User: {
   id
}

Post: {
   id,
   creator_id
}
```

And interesting part is here:
when I use dd line, I get what I wanted without any error

but when I use the real line I get error

```
Trying to get property 'profileImage' of non-object
```

I'm calling it in this line:

```
Model::with('posts')->find($id);
```

Comment: Are you calling it in a foreach loop?

Comment: @GertB. no I'm calling it from eager-loading of another model

Comment: You should always check if a relation exists before using a property from the relations model. If you use `dd()`the code stops running at that point. the reason why I think it's a loop is: if the first model contains the relation, dd() will work.

Comment: @GertB. I have one entry for each tables and references are all exist and checked. btw I edited the question, take a look.